# Is "neither I" grammatically correct?

Tags: word-order, negation, speech, grammatical-case, negative-polarity-items

I'm just trying to figure out if "neither I" is grammatically correct as a standalone statment (in spoken English).

Comment: ‘Nor I’ is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is grammatically unacceptable.

Correct constructions using **neither** include:

- **Neither *a* nor *b*:** This is the most common usage.

  > Neither Alaska nor Florida charges state income tax.
- **Neither *noun*:** You can use this variant when it's clear what you are referring to.

  > I moved from Alaska to Florida this year.  Fortunately, neither state charges income tax.
- ***Me* neither:** This may be close to what you had in mind.

  > "I don't like Brussels sprouts."
  >
  > "Me neither."
- **Neither:** This could be a one-word sentence.

  > "Do you prefer carrots or broccoli?"
  >
  > "Neither."

Answer (score -1):

As I said, I already heard "*Neither I*". If it would be grammaticaly incorrect indeed, this is the contraction for "Neither *(do)* I" where the verb is implicit like in : "he's faster than I" for than I *am*...

We also have :"*Neither I* nor Bruce *could* handle it" where a **third** part would also say : "Neither I" for "Nor I" or "me neither" or "me either I could not" BUT NOT "me either I could" to mean "could not" because *with the negative "either" can't match* here...

But we've worst like : He *DO* or "my baby just *CARE* for me" in the song...

Comment: This site is for learning English; we should model proper usage in our answers.